# FileUpload not working with UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, file-upload, updatepanel

I know about this problem but here i am with something different situation. I have three views and in third view, i am going to upload file. View can be change with buttons, they are outside of multiview. By default view1 will be displayed(cant change). I have to keep buttons in updatepanel which changes the views. On a button click i want to upload file in view3. Now those buttons which changes the view, when i click on one of them, i am not getting any changes in multiview. these are the problem.
Any help appriciate...
I googled, found some solution but most of them are not in multiview...
Also the problem is i am using MasterPages.
Thanks in advanced..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
We can Use AsyncFileUpload Control.
Also we need to add in form tag

```
enctype="multipart/data" method="post"
```

Need to add items from Toolbox and browse latest ajaxcontroltoolkit.
We can use it with UpdatePanel.
Only the thing is it will upload file as soon as you select the file to upload.
here is the link
 [click here to view e.g.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AsyncFileUpload.aspx?msg=3314381)

Cheers...